# Nhibernate with ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

Can I use NHibernate with my new ASP.NET 4.0 web Application without using Entity Framework and MVC?

When I run the website, no errors show but I'm not able to select the data from the database. Checking in detail, I found that there is an inner exception of dailect.

I'm using .NET 4.0 with Oracle 10g database.

---

Thanks all of you, My website runs.
when I'm using ASP.NET 4.0 Website, nhibernate code runs with showing data in gridview, but when i'm doing same with ASP.NET 4.0 project, data is not showing in the gridview but application is running in both & also that exception (Dialect One) is coming in both application when i see the detail of nhibernatehelper class object.

is there any diffrence, when we use nhibernate in website appliation and we use nhibernate in project appliation?

Comment: NHibernate has nothing to neither entity Framework nor MVC. Could you provide exception details?

Comment: First you say "no errors" but then you state there is an inner exception, which imply there would be an outer exception. Also, it's very likely that the problem can be understood fairly easily by looking at the exception messages and possibly their stack traces.

Comment: Thanks for answer gentlemen, My application is running successfully but I want to show the data into grid view there is no data in list. when I saw N Hibernate object then exception with this that is ((session.sessionfactory).Dialect).IdentityColumnString(), through a exception by nhibernate.mapping"
here session is variable of Isession 
when we find out more inner exception then exception is "could not find dialect"

please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NHibernate is an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) Framework. Entity Franework is also an ORM Framework. You could use one or the other or even both of them in the same ASP.NET application without any problem. NHibernate is not by any means tied to Entity Framework. They achieve similar functionality so you could choose of them to use in your application.

Comment: Thanks for answer sir, with nhibernate My application is running successfully but I want to show the data into grid view there is no data in list. when I saw N Hibernate object then exception with this that is ((session.sessionfactory).Dialect).IdentityColumnString(), through a exception by nhibernate.mapping" here session is variable of Isession when we find out more inner exception then exception is "could not find dialect" please help